# category in static library confused

Tags: xcode, linker, static-libraries, objective-c-category

unrecognized selector when using category in static library.

I searched in google and found this?
http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/03/13/static_objc_lib/

but I am still confused:

1、If I have `object.h/.m` and `object+category.h/.m`, and `#import "object+category.h"` in `object.m`, I add these to my project as source code, it works fine(no unrecognized selector error). But if I complie these to a static library and add to my project, crash with unrecognized selector.

So what's the different between these two ways? Why first way can find the selector and second way cannot?

2、The article says "As an optimization, the linker only chooses the object files that are required to resolve symbols." Same with static library and source code? Means If I have `object.h/.m` and `object+category.h/.m` as source code in my project and `object+category.h/.m` is never used. Will all those compiled `.o` files link to final .app?

3、How does the xcode linker know `object+category.o` is required and link it to .app if symbol is just created for each class, not each method? And when the link happen for `object+category.o`, compile time or runtime?